# Boyer-Moore Algorithm: Reaching the End of the Text

Tags: algorithm, boyer-moore

I'm working through this algorithm and the pattern and text are not matching up.

The text is: AADBCCAAA
The pattern is: CCAAA

I've created both the bad-symbol table and good-suffix table.

Bad Symbol:

! A C       (! represents letters not in the pattern)
5 1 3

Good-suffix:
k  d2
1  2
2  6
3  6
4  6
5  6

As for my searching:
AADBCCAAA
CCAAA            Since there is no match, shift 3 because C causes the mismatch

This lines up the right-most A in the pattern with the 2nd to last A in the text. This means

d1 = 3-2 = 1  and d2 = 6. The max of the two is 6 so shift 6.

With Boyer-Moore, does this mean since you can't shift 6, it will just compare the pattern with the end of the text and find the match or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Boyer-Moore is a tail first string searching algorithm, correct? So wouldn't all the characters line up after you shift it 4 times, where `k = 9`?

Comment: Shouldn't your shift value for C = 4 instead of 3? You shift one for the rightmost A (Position 1 starting from end), you shift six for unrecognized characters ('Position' 6 starting from end), but you shift three for the rightmost C (Position 4 from the end). I'm using 1-based indexing from the end.

Comment: Actually, for values not in the pattern, it should be ! = 5 not 6 as I had. But from my book it says the distance from the rightmost value among the first m-1 characters of the pattern to its last character. (m being the size). Therefore, I believe c should be 3.

Comment: Should k = 2 actually be 1 for the good-suffix?